# How to integrate JavaScript Compiler (like Jurassic, ClearScript) into Visual Studio 2010 shell

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-debugging, jurassic

I have a project in which I have to support javascript debugging from Jurassic or ClearScript or any other open source java script compiler for .net into to the Visual Studio 2010 Isolated shell. My requirement is that I can use F5, F10 and put a breakpoint so that I can debug custom java script code. I searched on the net lots, but couldnt find anything useful :-(. I have downloaded IronPthyon Isolated shell project, but it looks very complex and I just want to integrate already implemented compiler(jurassic, or clearscript) into the isolated shell.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can debug javascript in any modern browser. Why do you need it in Visual Studio?

Comment: As I said it is my requirement. I know that javascript can be debug in browser. Furthermore, I have my own custom functions which is not supported in browser javascript engine.

Comment: i am also looking answer for this question